# Different Classloader paths for Eclipse and IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Calling

```
getClass().getResource("./");
// or
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./");
```

from within my JUnit test has different results when executed in Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA:

- Eclipse: `C:/project/war/WEB-INF/classes/`
- IntelliJ: `C:/project/src/test/resources/`

All settings appear to be equal:

- output path: `C:/project/war/WEB-INF/classes`.
- working directory: `C:/project`
- classpath: source folders according to the Maven project structure (`src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`...)

My resources are located under `src/main/resources/mypackage`, my JUnit file under `src/test/java/mypackage`. When executed in Eclipse, the classloader points to the **output directory** (which contains both java classes and resources). In IntelliJ it points to the `src/test/resources` **source folder**.

How can I force IntelliJ to use the output directory for my classloader? Alternatively, how can I force it to use the *right* source folder `src/main/resources` where my resources are located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Intellij, right click on src/main/resources, then select
Mark Directory As -> Resources Root